# Не получается выбрать элемент с помощью document.querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript

Я - новичок. В указанном HTML с помощью чистого JS не получается корректно выбрать все 3 элемента с классом ***slider__button***
А именно в ***Nodelist*** первый элемент пустой (который должен соответствовать элементу

`<li class="slider__button slider__button_active">`),

другие два корректные.
Подскажите, плиз, что делаю не так.

Код:

```js
let sliderButton = document.querySelectorAll(".slider__button");

console.log(sliderButton);
```

```html
<ul class="slider">
  <li class="slider__button slider__button_active">
    <a href="#" class="slider__button-link slider__button-link_active">1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="slider__button">
    <a href="#" class="slider__button-link">2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="slider__button">
    <a href="#" class="slider__button-link">3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> первый элемент пустой

Что это значит?

---

```js
let sliderButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".slider__button");
for (let i = 0; i < sliderButtons.length; i++) {
  console.log(sliderButtons[i].innerText);
}
```

```html
    <ul class="slider">
      <li class="slider__button slider__button_active">
        <a href="#" class="slider__button-link slider__button-link_active">1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="slider__button">
        <a href="#" class="slider__button-link">2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="slider__button">
        <a href="#" class="slider__button-link">3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Нормально ты через for фигачишь, императивный подход!

Comment: Спасибо! Разобрался!

Comment: @РоманБеспалов Пожалуйста. Успехов.